# Script to create postgres user with whoami

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, command-line, postgresql-9.3

I'm making a script to automate the process to install and create a new postgres user, the problem is that I will not ever know the name of the local user where the script will run, so I tried this with no results:

```
LOCALUSER=whoami
sudo su - postgres -c "psql -U postgres -d template1 -c \"create user ${LOCALUSER} with createdb;\""
```

It creates a new user but named "whoami", as you could guess, I need the current user name instead "whoami".

How can I pass the user name?
Thank you in advance!
Best Regards
Alejandro

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
LOCALUSER="$(whoami)"
```

Instead of:

```
LOCALUSER=whoami
```

Did the trick.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175415/forward-function-and-variables-into-sudo-su-user-eof